# Paypal PHP SDK Credications and Authentication, I can't get it to work

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using the official PHP Paypal SDK here: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

I'm confused how authentication works. My real paypal account gives me: username, password, signature. My paypal dev account gives me: ClientID and Secret. My sandbox business user gives me a username, password, and signature.

The docs say I can authenticate as follows:

```
$cred = new PPCertificateCredential("username", "password", "path-to-pem-file");
$cred->setThirdPartyAuthorization(new PPTokenAuthorization("accessToken", "tokenSecret"));
$response = $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq, $cred);
```

What values do I use here from the sandbox to authenticate with the sand box? What values do I use when I switch over to live? What about the config file, it says I can with that.

Please help, i'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your REST credentials from within your developer account.  Once logged into your developer account, click on the "Applications" tab, then click on "REST API Credentils link.  Here you will see the Client ID and Secret.  There will also be instructions on that page for obtaining your live credentials as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you use the sandbox api credentials as follows:

1. use the business account created as one of your sandbox account. (applications tab, sandbox accounts). Click on the account, then on "profile" under it, then on the "API Credentials" tab.
2. edit the sdk_config.ini in the php sdk (under the config folder), and use those credintials with an app_id of APP-80W284485P519543T
3. Make sure mode is set to sandbox under [Service] in the ini file.

When you make the service call use the account username you entered in the ini file as follows:

```
$setECResponse = $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq,"API_USERNAME");
```